# Query to find the number of paying customers and churned customers?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table paid_users that looks like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d25ba

I am trying to determine paying customers grouped by Month-Year and churned customers grouped by Month-Year. Essentially, there are payors and users. A payor is whoever is paying for that specific user. If there is no payment_stop_date, that means the payor is still paying for the user. The payment_stop_date indicates if/when the payor has stopped paying for the user.

I want to find the number of paying customers in which the result of the query should be:

```
Month-Year | New Paying Customers | Churned Paying Customers
------------------------------------------------------------
11-2014    | 1                    |
12-2014    |                      | 1
01-2015    | 1                    |
04-2015    |                      |
06-2015    | 2                    |
07-2015    | 1                    |
10-2015    |                      | 1
```

Looking at payor_id 3453, she started paying for user_id 3182 in 11-2014 so she would be included in the 11-2014 group. However, she stopped paying for two users in 12-2014 so is included in that churned 12-2014 group. A payor is considered a churned paying customer if they have completely stopped paying us (ie they could have been paying for one person then cancelled. Or in this case, payor_id 3453 was paying for 2 users then cancelled). Payor_3453 then started paying for user_id 4716 in 01-2015 so she is then included in the 01-2015 group.

I am having difficulty writing a query for this as it's not necessarily distinct payor_id since payor_id 3453 is considered a new paying customer twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood this right: for every month you want to know how many customer started paying for their first user and how many customers stopped paying for their last user?

Solution seems rather complicated but maybe it's not that easy after all.

```
with months as 
(
    select * from 
    generate_series('2014-06-01', now() at time zone 'utc', interval '1 month') as month
    cross join paid_users
)
, sums as
(
    select month, payor_id, joiners, leavers, sum(net) over (partition by payor_id order by month) 
    from
    (
        select month, payor_id, joiners, leavers, coalesce(joiners,0) - coalesce(leavers, 0) as net
        from
        (
            select payor_id, month, count(*) as joiners
            from months
            where payment_start_date >= month
            and payment_start_date < month + interval '1 month'
            group by month, payor_id
        ) as t
        full join
        (
            select payor_id, month, count(*) as leavers
            from months
            where payment_stop_date >= month
            and payment_stop_date < month + interval '1 month'
            group by month, payor_id
        ) as u
        using (month, payor_id)
    ) as v
)

select * from sums
order by payor_id, sum
```

The above should give you total paid users for every customer

```
        month        | payor_id | joiners | leavers | sum 
---------------------+----------+---------+---------+-----
 2014-06-01 00:00:00 |     1725 |       1 |         |   1
 2014-06-01 00:00:00 |     1929 |       1 |         |   1
 2015-10-01 00:00:00 |     1929 |         |       1 |   0
 2014-06-01 00:00:00 |     1986 |       1 |         |   1
 2014-11-01 00:00:00 |     3453 |       2 |         |   2
 2014-12-01 00:00:00 |     3453 |         |       2 |   0
 2015-01-01 00:00:00 |     3453 |       1 |         |   1
 2015-03-01 00:00:00 |     3453 |       1 |         |   2
 2015-04-01 00:00:00 |     3453 |       2 |       1 |   3
 2015-05-01 00:00:00 |     3453 |         |       1 |   2
 2015-06-01 00:00:00 |     3453 |         |       1 |   1
 2015-10-01 00:00:00 |     3453 |       1 |         |   2
 2015-07-01 00:00:00 |     6499 |       1 |         |   1
 2015-08-01 00:00:00 |     6499 |       3 |         |   4
 2015-10-01 00:00:00 |     6499 |         |       1 |   3
 2015-11-01 00:00:00 |     6499 |         |       1 |   2
```

So new customers are customers who go from sum 0 to a non-zero sum, churned customers are customer who reach a sum of 0?

```
select month, new, churned from
(
    (
        select month, count(*) as churned
        from sums
        where sum = 0
        group by month
    ) as l
    full join
    (
        select month, count(*) as new
        from (
            select month, payor_id, sum, coalesce(lag(sum) over (partition by payor_id order by month), 0) as prev_sum
            from sums
            order by payor_id, month
        ) as t
        where prev_sum = 0 and sum > 0
        group by month
    ) as r
    using (month)
)
order by month
```

Outputs

```
        month        | new | churned 
---------------------+-----+---------
 2014-06-01 00:00:00 |   3 |        
 2014-11-01 00:00:00 |   1 |        
 2014-12-01 00:00:00 |     |       1
 2015-01-01 00:00:00 |   1 |        
 2015-07-01 00:00:00 |   1 |        
 2015-10-01 00:00:00 |     |       1
```

Hope this helps. If someone knows an easier way I'd be pleased to hear about it.

Comment: This seems very reasonable and you definitely explained the idea of the question better than me - thank you so much for the help! The numbers look right and the logic makes a lot of sense :)